# trigger event with dynamic elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```
function getAnnoDetailsForTeacher(){
    
    var tcounter = 1;
    
    $.ajax({
        url:'<%=contextPath%>/show/announcementsForTeacher',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
        },
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            'loginId' : '${loginId}'
        },
        success:function(data){
            
            $('#annoTable tbody').empty();
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
            {
             var aid = data[i].id;
             var date = data[i].date;
             var subject = data[i].subject;
             var details = data[i].details;
             var status = data[i].status;
             $('#annoTable tbody').append('<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewTAnnoModal"><td id="tCounter'+aid+'"><strong>'+tcounter+
                                          '</strong></td><td id="tDate'+aid+'"><strong>'+date+
                                          '</strong></td><td id="tSubject'+aid+'"><strong>'+ subject +
                                          '</strong></td><td id="tDetails'+aid+'" class="cell expand-small-on-hover"><strong>'+ details +
                                          '</strong></td><td><button type="button" id="tAnnoBtn'+aid+'" onclick="viewTAnno()" class="viewbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" style="display:block;">View</button>'+
                                          '</td>'+
                                         ......+
                                          '</tr>');
             tcounter += 1;
            }
            $('#tnoti').empty();
            $('#tnoti').css('display','block');
            $('#tnoti').append(tcounter-1);
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
    return tcounter;
    
}
```

my goal is to unbold a row when clicked on view btn (where id is dynamic:i d="tAnnoBtn'+aid+'") inside the jQuery.

Here is the unbold jQuery

```
$('#tAnnoForm').on('click', '.viewbtn', function() {
    const fooTCounter = document.getElementById("tCounter");
      fooTCounter.innerHTML = fooTCounter
        .innerHTML
        .replace(/<strong>/g, "")
        .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "");


      const fooTDate = document.getElementById("tDate");
      fooTDate.innerHTML = fooTDate
        .innerHTML
        .replace(/<strong>/g, "")
        .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "");
    


      const fooTSubject = document.getElementById("tSubject");
      fooTSubject.innerHTML = fooTSubject
        .innerHTML
        .replace(/<strong>/g, "")
        .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "");
    


      const fooTDetails = document.getElementById("tDetails");
      fooTDetails.innerHTML = fooTDetails
        .innerHTML
        .replace(/<strong>/g, "")
        .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "");
    });
```

problem is every element is created dynamically with dynamic id (td cells and buttons)
so how can i input the dynamic ids inside the unbold jQuery??
like in jQuery it should go like document.getElementById("tCounter1") where 1 is concatenated with tCounter.
also in '.viewbtn', it should go like '#tAnnoBtn1' where 1 is dynamically concatenated with tAnnoBtn.

check this viewTAnno(aid) function

```
function viewTAnno(aid)
{
    var viewed;
    
    $.ajax({
        url:'<%=contextPath%>/show/annoViewedForTeacher',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
        },
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            'loginId' : '${loginId}',
            'anno_id' : aid
        },
        success:function(data){
            //alert("New Announcement Added Successsfully");
            
            console.log(data);
            viewed =data;
            $('#tAnnoTable').on('click', '.viewbtn', function() {
                if(viewed==0){
                  //get closest tr > loop through tds
                  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last)").each(function() {
                    //replace text
                    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/<strong>/g, "")
                      .replace(/<\/strong>/g, ""))
                      //tcounter=tcounter-1;
                      $.ajax({
                        url:'<%=contextPath%>/show/annoViewedForTeacher',
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
                        },
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {
                            'loginId' : '${loginId}',
                            'anno_id' : aid
                        },
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            
                            
                        },
                        error:function(e){
                            console.log(e)
                        }
                    });
                    
                    
                  })
                }
            })
                
        
            
            
            
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
    
    return viewed;
    
}
```

[image: Announcements Table]

i want to unbold a particular row upon clicking on view so that it also changes in db just like gmail inbox. how can i do that?

Comment: This can be done far simpler by toggling a class on the parent row and using css rules

Comment: @charlietfl if you can elaborate the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate through your `tds` where `view` button has been clicked then using `$(this).text(..)` replace `<strong>` tag with `''`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#annoTable').on('click', '.viewbtn', function() {
  //get closest tr > loop through tds
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last)").each(function() {
    //replace text
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/<strong>/g, "")
      .replace(/<\/strong>/g, ""))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="annoTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewTAnnoModal">
      <td id="tCounter1"><strong>1</strong></td>
      <td id="tDate1"><strong>0.005997001499250375</strong></td>
      <td id="tSubject1"><strong>Abc</strong></td>
      <td id="tDetails1" class="cell expand-small-on-hover"><strong>Somwthing..</strong></td>
      <td><button type="button" id="tAnnoBtn1" onclick="viewTAnno()" class="viewbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" style="display:block;">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewTAnnoModal">
      <td id="tCounter2"><strong>2</strong></td>
      <td id="tDate2"><strong>0.005997001499250375</strong></td>
      <td id="tSubject2"><strong>Abc</strong></td>
      <td id="tDetails2" class="cell expand-small-on-hover"><strong>Somwthing..</strong></td>
      <td><button type="button" id="tAnnoBtn2" onclick="viewTAnno()" class="viewbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" style="display:block;">View</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @swati , it does work, can you help me one more thing, in my website  i want to change the td cells permanently. after logout it becomes bold again. how can do that?

Comment: You need to do that at your server code . Add one extra field for view set it `true` or `false` for each record and while appending row check if it is false then put strong tag or not .

Comment: hello @Swati , can you explain this line $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last)").each(function()..... what i am trying to achieve is to unbold the row (viewed =true in db) for that particular id, but in db it only changes the first row , when calling ajax inside that jquery loop u given.

Comment: Hi, that line means get closest `tr` from `td` which is click and select all `tds` inside that tr expect the last one because the last one has button inside it .

Comment: hello @Swati , check my viewTAnno function above. you will understand

Comment: Your ajax code should not be inside each loop put that outside `each` loop and which value you need to pass to backend `slno` ? what is `aid` ? your current is all wrong here you are nesting ajax inside ajax no need to do that .

Comment: no, slno is just a counter, i want to append viewed as true in db for that particular aid (not same as slno).

Comment: so here `onclick="viewTAnno("+aid+")"` you are already passing `aid` am i right?

Comment: see viewTAnno(aid) in on onclick to another function fetching from backend. what i am trying to do, in outer ajax GET the viewed value for that particular aid and loginId, if viewed is 0, in inner ajax POST viewed =1 for that particular aid, when clicking on btn in jquery

Comment: Okay just change here `onclick="viewTAnno("+aid+",this)"` here pass `this` as well inside your function and then change your js code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ng69x30d/1/).

Comment: Hi @Swati , this works but again next login it's coming bold again, though this time upon clicking row is not unbloding ovio beacuse in db, it set to true

Comment: next time login ? what do you mean by that ? Also , you can ask new question for that issue will help there if i know solutions :)

Comment: hi @Swati, yes, in my site there is a session for every user, this feature is under a user login, then only he can do the bold unbold thing. may i connect with you skype or hangout?

Comment: Sorry i cannot share that . Please , ask another question will help you there  :)